# Is Zend Framework 1.12 compatible with a Raspberry Pi web server?

Tags: zend-framework, raspberry-pi

My question is simple: I have developed a light shopping website on Zend Framework 1.12.3. It's now live on my Raspberry Pi and it is super slow! CSS effects are slow, so is the pages loading.
My system is:

```
512Mb RAM
700Mhz processor
32Gb space on memory card (82% free)
Web server: Lighttpd
Distribution: Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
Kernel: Linux 3.6.11+ armv6l
```

Do you know the server hardware requirements for Zend Framework?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to check it on some other server too to check if problem is with Zend or with your code (you may want to read about xdebug and database profiler). CSS for example is frontend part so it makes no difference how fast server is.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will check my code: I may have a few `Zend_Debug::dump()` left in some parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had left a `Zend_Debug::dump($app)` in `public/index.php` what was making all the application going slow! Thanks!